# Laravel: left join + order c null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Допустим есть табличка с людьми

> - **id...name**
> - 1......Максим
> - 2......Юля
> - 3......Денис
> - 4......Маша
> - 5......Кристина

И есть табличка с их возрастами

> - **user_id..age**
> - 1..........13
> - 2..........21
> - 3..........9
> - 5..........33

То есть для *Маши(4)* значения возраста нет, и мы хотим, чтобы тогда по-умолчанию считалось, что ей 18. И как бы сделать *left join* , а потом *orderby* по возрасту, чтобы это  учитывалось, и выводилось не

> - **id..age..имя**
> - 3.....9....Денис
> - 1.....13...Максим
> - 2.....21...Юля
> - 5.....33...Кристина
> - 4.....null.Маша

а

> - **id..age..имя**
> - 3.....9....Денис
> - 1.....13...Максим
> - 4.....18...Маша
> - 2.....21...Юля
> - 5.....33...Кристина

Интересно решение на чистом sql, и на php laravel

Comment: Первый возникающий вопрос, если не нужна гибкость, почему в дефолт для age не прописать 18?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select u.id,
   ifnull(a.age, 18) as user_age,
   u.name
from user u
   left join age a on u.id = a.id
order by user_age
```

Для реализации на php laravel [почитайте доки](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries), где всё подробно расписано.

Comment: IF кстати можно сократить до IFNULL(a.age, 18)

Comment: @Firepro заработался, не пришло на ум `nvl`, `coalesce` и `ifnull` :)

Comment: :) Раз поменяли, is null еще уберите пожалуйста, оно там не нужно в первом аргументе :)

Comment: @Firepro совсем сильно заработался, спасибо за замечание :)

Comment: Практически хорошо: но такое ощущение, что он сначала сортирует, а потом заменяет null на 18. То есть, тоже самое, как у меня в вопросе (3я цитата) - только вместо null - 18.

Comment: @memberKPSS не должен, в запросе всегда сначала select, и только потом order by выполняются. Чисто ради интереса - если обернуть написанный мной запрос в вид `select * from (мой_запрос) t order by t.user_age` - сортировка такая же кривая?

Comment: Оказалось просто руки кривые у меня, и так и так работает)

Answer (score -1):

На чистом SQL думаю примерно так

```
SELECT 
   `U`.`id` as `user_id`, 
   `U`.`name` as `name`, 
   IF(`A`.`age` = NULL, 18, `A`.`age`) as `age`  
FROM `users` as `U`
   LEFT JOIN `age` as `A`
      ON `U`.`id` = `A`.`User_id`
ORDER BY age
```

Eloquent

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('age', 'users.id', '=', 'age.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', DB::raw('IF(A.age = NULL, 18, A.age) as age'))
            ->orderBy('age', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

Comment: 1. равняться `null` не может; 2. `join` уберет `null`.